# How do I sort through a CSV file in python so that it only returns certain values?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to sort through a CSV file in python so that only a certain value from each entry is printed. Each line of my csv files has the date, location, weather, temperature, etc. I am trying to return the temperature column, but instead it is printing the entire csv file. This is what I currently have:

```
with open('2000-2009.csv', newline = "") as csv_file:

  csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter = ',')
  temp = 0
  tempList = []
  index = 0


  for Tavg in csv_reader:
      temp = int(Tavg)
      tempList.append(temp)

  print(tempList)
```

Comment: With each iteration over `csv_reader`, you get a list with the items in that line. You can index that list to get the value of interest.

Answer (score 0):

that's because you are importing the entire CSV file. you want to extract the column. add a counter based on the number of columns and read it when the counter hits the column.

Comment: How exactly would I do that?